# Can't compile Cython function with multiple input arguments

Tags: cython

I am trying to get Cython running and I think I'm almost there but have hit a snag that I do not understand. I can compile functions with a single argument, but not with multiple. I have this issue with python 3.3, but not 2.7.

I successfully compiled and ran "hello world" and fibonacci examples but when I try to compile anything with two or more input arguments I get an error when compiling.

To boil it down to a very simple case. This compiles, imports to python, and runs.

```
def cycheckadd(c):
    b = 1
    d = b + c
    return d
```

This does not.

```
def cycheckadd(b,c):
    d = b + c
    return d
```

And returns the following error when building.

```
    C:\Users\Chris\PycharmProjects\CythonTest>python setup.py build_ext --inplace
Compiling cycheck.pyx because it changed.
Cythonizing cycheck.pyx
running build_ext
building 'cycheck' extension
creating build
creating build\temp.win32-3.3
creating build\temp.win32-3.3\Release
c:\mingw\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -IC:\WinPython-32bit-3.3.5.9\python-3.3.5\include -IC:\WinPython-32bit-3.3.5.9\python-3.3.5\include -c cycheck.c -o build\temp.win32-3.3\Release\
cycheck.o
writing build\temp.win32-3.3\Release\cycheck.def
creating build\lib.win32-3.3
c:\mingw\bin\gcc.exe -shared -s build\temp.win32-3.3\Release\cycheck.o build\temp.win32-3.3\Release\cycheck.def -LC:\WinPython-32bit-3.3.5.9\python-3.3.5\libs -LC:\WinPython-32bit-3
.3.5.9\python-3.3.5\PCbuild -lpython33 -lmsvcr100 -o build\lib.win32-3.3\cycheck.pyd
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../libmsvcrt.a(dupvs00137.o):(.idata$5+0x0): multiple definition of `_imp___assert'
C:\WinPython-32bit-3.3.5.9\python-3.3.5\libs/libmsvcr100.a(dqcgs00457.o):(.idata$5+0x0): first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Compiled using the setup.py file below.

```
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    name = 'cython math check',
    ext_modules = cythonize("cycheck.pyx"),
)
```

This result was generated using python 3.3 and cython 0.22. I do not have this problem when I use 2.7.

The compiler is MinGW. I have been using 32bit versions of Python on Windows 10-64bit. I have added the following config file to the python directory.

C:\WinPython-32bit-3.3.5.9\python-3.3.5\Lib\distutils\distutils.cfg

```
[build]
compiler = mingw32

[build_ext]
compiler = mingw32
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: do you have both of those methods in the same program with the same name? try changing one of the names.

Comment: For this example I changed the method and recompiled, so there is only ever one method that always has the same name... But I've also tried changing the method name, as well as the .pyx file name, but no luck...

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work? (i.e. have you tried importing it?) The messages you give in your question are warnings (and they warn about something build into Cython, so it isn't something you need to worry about yourself) rather than errors, so shouldn't stop it compiling the module.

Comment: You are correct sir! I got so caught up just seeing an error I didn't check if it had imported! So I am able to compile both methods with python 2.7, but I get a different error when using 3.3. I'll update the question to reflect the 3.3 issue that I still have. Thank you!, at least I can proceed with 2.7.

Comment: @Chris I'm afraid I don't know about your 3.3 error. My only advice would to try upgrading to WinPython 3.4 (http://winpython.github.io/) which may have bug fixes. It's a guess though! I don't have any real reason to think this will help.